# To update specific Item in credhub

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a few secrets maintained in credhub service in PCF.
There are many secrets associated to the application maintained in one credhub service.
My question is how can we edit a single secret password without affecting other secrets(name/key values) in the same credhub instance.

If I update with `cf update-service CredhubMySecrets -c "{\"dbpwd\": \"dkdsnkdnf\"}"` and restage, this overrides or deletes other secrets also, I could see that only existing key name is `dbpwd:dkdsnkdnf`

And via PCF UI app manager also if we update via settings , the effect is the same...

So is there any way to update a particular key value with a cli command or UI app manager so that all the existing `name:value` pairs should not be lost along with the changed item?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same thing. My solution for right now is to maintain a JSON file with all the credentials for the Credhub service. If I want to edit a single credential, I open the JSON, make my edit, then run the command:

```html
cf update-service SERVICE_NAME -c /path/to/json
```

This way all the credentials are re-uploaded with the edited one.
How are you viewing the credentials in the Apps Manager? Once I make the credhub service I am unable to view the credentials again (in both in the Apps manager and through the cli)